# How to store messages in list received from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am developing a code related to receive messages through broadcast receivers.

based on the fallowing code

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

i want to store all i received messages  in  list and

display the received messages when i want in a list format.

Comment: your question is not clear, in what part of it are you actually facing a problem?

Comment: in toast i display the getting message.i want to store that message in  a list.And retrive.

Comment: is the toast able to display it/

Comment: i don't want to display message by toast.i want to display messages by list(if i store all messages in a list).

Comment: Then all you need to do is collect all the messages in a String array and create a list with the adapter passing the string array as parameter whenever you want to display the messages in a list.

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible ways: store it in database or in file. I think, better way is to use SQLite. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) is docs how to create simple database, store values, and receive it when necessary. Also there is docs how to read and write to files.